# Defining a new unit in siunitx that has a subscript

Tags: siunitx

I would like to define a new unit, analogous to `\electronmass`, in the `siunitx` package but this time for the proton mass. So I just copy/pasted the definition of `\electronmass` from the style file and modified it. See MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\DeclareSIUnit[]\protonmass
{ \text { \ensuremath { m _ { \textup { p } } } } }

\begin{document}

electron mass = \si{\electronmass}

proton mass = \si{\protonmass}

\end{document}
```

If I look at the output, there is a small space between the 'm' and the 'p'. [image].

How should I define the \protonmass unit so that the space is gone?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the spaces from the definition. The reason why the space doesn't occur for `\electronmass` is I'd think that `siunitx` is an `expl3` package, and in the environment defined by `expl3` spaces in the input are all ignored. Your new definition is not written in that environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\DeclareSIUnit[]\protonmass
{\text{\ensuremath{m_{\textup{p}}}}}

\begin{document}

electron mass = \si{\electronmass}

proton mass = \si{\protonmass}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output.

[image]

Comment: I think Joseph should have the definitions of units in a different file not evaluated under `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Answer (score 13):

After the definition

```
\DeclareSIUnit[]\protonmass
{ \text { \ensuremath { m _ { \textup { p } } } } }
```

the replacement text for `\protonmass` becomes

```
•\text{•\ensuremath{•m•_{•\textup{•p•}•}•}•}•
```

where `•` denotes a space token. The third, fourth, fifth, eighth and ninth space tokens get ignored, because they happen to be evaluated in math mode. The remaining ones aren't (but the outer ones are removed by `siunitx`) because they're in *text* mode. So you still get the second, sixth, seventh and tenth space tokens: a total of four. Indeed

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\DeclareSIUnit[]\protonmass
{ \text { \ensuremath { m _ { \textup { p } } } } }

\begin{document}

X\si{\electronmass}X

X\si{\protonmass}X

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

where the four spaces are clearly visible.

Correct definition

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\protonmass}{%
 \text{$m_{\textup{p}}$}%
}

\begin{document}

X\si{\electronmass}X

X\si{\protonmass}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes

1. `\ensuremath` is not needed, because you *know* to be in text mode
2. Joseph Wright, the package author, should provide the unit definitions in a different file not under `\ExplSyntaxOn`, in order to provide a model for further definitions.